# String[] values vs String values[]

Tags: java, arrays, string

i was wondering whats the difference between these two

```
String values[] = new String[10]

String[] values = new String[10]
```

Both of these are used the same way. We can manipulate data in them the same way so whats the difference.

[The Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) uses the latter one for declaring arrays. Which one should we use ?

Comment: As, JavaDoc prefer, Use second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to language [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html):

> The [] may appear as part of the type at the beginning of the
>   declaration, or as part of the declarator for a particular variable,
>   or both.

So yes they are the same. 
For example:

```
byte[] rowvector, colvector, matrix[];
```

This declaration is equivalent to:

```
byte rowvector[], colvector[], matrix[][];
```

Answer (score 1):

both are same .these are just different forms of array declaration
Following are the different ways of array declarations

```
    String[] x = new String[3];
    String[] x = {"a","b","c"};
    String[] x = new String[]{"a","b","c"};

    String x[] = new String[3];
    String x[] = {"a","b","c"};
    String x[] = new String[]{"a","b","c"};
```

In all the cases `x.length` will output 3

Answer (score 0):

Really only a matter of personal preference. I Prefer `String[]`, as it makes clear that the [] belongs to the type of the variable. But I guess reasons for using the old syntax can be found, too.

Answer (score 0):

They're equivalent.

The first one is more c style syntax, so they kept it in java.

Answer (score 0):

Both are valid syntax, and result in the exact same bytecode.
Oracle's (and formally Sun's) convention is to use the latter form (`String[] values = new String[10]`), as would almost any open source project you encounter - i.e., this is the one you should use.

Answer (score 0):

According to [JLS on Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2)

> The [] may appear as part of the type at the beginning of the declaration, or as part of the declarator for a particular variable, or both.